# Error connecting to MySQL server after creating a Docker container

Tags: mysql, linux

Working on a Ubuntu 22.04 system with MySQL 8. I have a legacy collection of MySQL data/dbs on an external harddrive that I used a Docker container and MySQL image to connect to and export.  This worked fine, but when I attempt to connect to my existing MySQL installation via command line I'm getting the following error despite the server showing as 'active' via `systemctl`:

```
chris@chris-X1C6:~$ mysql -u admin -p
Enter password:
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/tmp/mysql.sock' (2)
```

I've googled and found a [few](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22290519/mysql-error-2002-hy000-cant-connect-to-local-mysql-server-through-socket-v) (and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19658891/error-2002-hy000-cant-connect-to-local-mysql-server-through-socket-var-run)) remedies, none of which fix the issue.  System restart doesn't address either.

As a first common sense check, I don't see a mysql sock file in the `/tmp` location referenced, but do see one (`mysqld.sock`) located in the `/var/run/mysqld` directory.  I also don't see a .cnf file to inspect in the mysql directory (`/var/lib/mysql`).

What else should I be looking at?